# Deep diving into the implementation of closures

Tags: c#, closures

Consider the following code block:

```
int x = 1;
D foo = () =>
{
    Console.WriteLine(x);
    x = 2;
};

x = 3;
foo();
Console.WriteLine(x);
```

The output is: 3,2. I'm trying to understand what happens behind the scenes when this code is running.

The compiler generates this new class:
[image]

The question if how does the **x** variable get's changed. How does the x inside <>_DiplayClass1 is changing the x inside Program class. Is it doing something like this behind the scenes?

```
var temp = new <>c_DisplayClass1();
temp.x = this.x;
temp.<Main>b_0();
this.x = temp.x;
```

Comment: how you got the compiler generated class ?? just asking for inforrmation

Comment: @EhsanSajjad you can use IL decompilers, such as ILSpy or JetBrains DotPeek.

Comment: Or for looking at small pieces of code, I often use [TryRoslyn](http://goo.gl/gx0E0h) that is online and does the compilation + decompilation (and that can even show IL code directly)

Comment: @xanatos That's brilliant, I didn't know about that one! Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It helps to look at the fully de-compiled code:

```
// Decompiled with JetBrains decompiler
// Type: Program
// Assembly: test, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null
// MVID: D26FF17C-3FD8-4920-BEFC-ED98BC41836A
// Assembly location: C:\temp\test.exe
// Compiler-generated code is shown

using System;
using System.Runtime.CompilerServices;

internal static class Program
{
  private static void Main()
  {
    Program.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1 cDisplayClass1 = new Program.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1();
    cDisplayClass1.x = 1;
    // ISSUE: method pointer
    Action action = new Action((object) cDisplayClass1, __methodptr(\u003CMain\u003Eb__0));
    cDisplayClass1.x = 3;
    action();
    Console.WriteLine(cDisplayClass1.x);
  }

  [CompilerGenerated]
  private sealed class \u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1
  {
    public int x;

    public \u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1()
    {
      base.\u002Ector();
    }

    public void \u003CMain\u003Eb__0()
    {
      Console.WriteLine(this.x);
      this.x = 2;
    }
  }
}
```

Specifically, look at how `Main` got re-written:

```
  private static void Main()
  {
    Program.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1 cDisplayClass1 = new Program.\u003C\u003Ec__DisplayClass1();
    cDisplayClass1.x = 1;
    // ISSUE: method pointer
    Action action = new Action((object) cDisplayClass1, __methodptr(\u003CMain\u003Eb__0));
    cDisplayClass1.x = 3;
    action();
    Console.WriteLine(cDisplayClass1.x);
  }
```

You see that the `x` being affected is attached to the closure class generated from the code. The following line changes `x` to 3:

```
    cDisplayClass1.x = 3;
```

And this is the same `x` that the method behind `action` is referring to.

Answer (score 3):

If you'd look what happens in `Main`, you'd see this:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0 <>c__DisplayClass0_ = new Program.<>c__DisplayClass0_0();
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.x = 1;
    Action action = new Action(<>c__DisplayClass0_.<Main>b__0);
    <>c__DisplayClass0_.x = 3;
    action();
    Console.WriteLine(<>c__DisplayClass0_.x);
}

[CompilerGenerated]
private sealed class <>c__DisplayClass0_0
{
    public int x;

    internal void <Main>b__0()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(this.x);
        this.x = 2;
    }
}
```

This makes things more clear. You see that the lifted `x` member gets set twice, once to `1` and then `3`. Inside `b__0`, it gets set again to `2`. Thus, you see that the actual change happens to the *same member*. That is what happens when you close over variables. **The actual variable** gets lifted, not it's value.

Answer (score 2):

Because `x` is a local variable, your method can be translated to something equivalent (but not equal) to this:

```
int x = 1;
var closure = new <>c_DisplayClass1();
closure.x = x;

closure.x = 3;                      // x = 3
closure.<Main>b_0();                // foo();
Console.WriteLine(closure.x);       // Console.WriteLine(x)
```

In other words, uses of the variable `x`are replaced with `closure.x`

Answer (score 1):

According to C# in a nutshell :

lambda expression can reference the local variables and parameters of the method
in which it’s defined (outer variables).

### Example:

```
int factor = 2;
Func<int, int> multiplier = n => n * factor;
Console.WriteLine (multiplier (3));    // outputs 6
```

### Captured Variables and Closure:

Outer variables referenced by a lambda expression are called **captured variables**. A
lambda expression that captures variables is called a **closure**.

**Captured variables** are evaluated when the delegate is actually invoked, not when
the variables were captured

### For Example:

```
int factor = 2;
Func<int, int> multiplier = n => n * factor;
factor = 10;
Console.WriteLine (multiplier (3)); // output is 30
```

Lambda expressions can themselves update captured variables:

```
int seed = 0;
Func<int> natural = () => seed++;
Console.WriteLine (natural()); // 0
Console.WriteLine (natural()); // 1

Console.WriteLine (seed); // 2
```

**Captured variables** have their lifetimes extended to that of the delegate.

In the following
example, the local variable seed would ordinarily disappear from scope when
Natural finished executing. But because seed has been captured, its lifetime is
extended to that of the capturing delegate, natural:

```
static Func<int> Natural()
{
int seed = 0;
return () => seed++; // Returns a closure
}

static void Main()
{
Func<int> natural = Natural();
Console.WriteLine (natural()); // 0
Console.WriteLine (natural()); // 1
}
```

A local variable instantiated within a lambda expression is unique per invocation of
the delegate instance. If we refactor our previous example to instantiate seed
within the lambda expression, we get a different (in this case, undesirable) result:

```
static Func<int> Natural()
{
return() => { int seed = 0; return seed++; };
}
static void Main()
{
Func<int> natural = Natural();
Console.WriteLine (natural()); // 0
Console.WriteLine (natural()); // 0
}
```

> > **Capturing is internally implemented by “hoisting” the captured
> >     variables into fields of a private class. When the method is
> >     called, the class is instantiated and lifetime-bound to the delegate
> >     instance.**

### Capturing iteration variables

When you capture the iteration variable of a for loop, C# treats that variable as
though it was declared outside the loop. This means that the same variable is captured
in each iteration. The following program writes 333 instead of writing 012:

```
Action[] actions = new Action[3];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
actions [i] = () => **Console.Write (i)**; // closure here
foreach (Action a in actions) a(); // 333
```

Each closure (shown in boldface) captures the same variable, i. (This actually makes
sense when you consider that i is a variable whose value persists between loop iterations;
you can even explicitly change i within the loop body if you want.) The
consequence is that when the delegates are later invoked, each delegate sees i’s value
at the time of invocation—which is 3.

The above example is equal to this:

```
Action[] actions = new Action[3];
int i = 0;
actions[0] = () => Console.Write (i);
i = 1;
actions[1] = () => Console.Write (i);
i = 2;
actions[2] = () => Console.Write (i);
i = 3;
foreach (Action a in actions) a(); // 333
```

### Breaking Change to Note in C# 5:

Prior to C# 5.0, foreach loops worked in the same way.

Consider this example:

```
Action[] actions = new Action[3];
int i = 0;
foreach (char c in "abc")
actions [i++] = () => Console.Write (c);

foreach (Action a in actions) a();
```

it will output **ccc** in **C# 4.0** , but in **C# 5.0** it will output **abc**.

Quote from book:

> > This caused considerable confusion: unlike with a for loop, the
> >     iteration variable in a foreach loop is immutable, and so one
> >     would expect it to be treated as local to the loop body. The good
> >     news is that it’s been fixed in C# 5.0, and the example above
> >     now writes “abc.”
> >
> > Technically, this is a breaking change because recompiling a C#
> >     4.0 program in C# 5.0 could create a different result. In general,
> >     the C# team tries to avoid breaking changes; however in this
> >     case, a “break” would almost certainly indicate an undetected
> >     bug in the C# 4.0 program rather than intentional reliance on
> >     the old behavior.

Answer (score -2):

What is happening is that `int x` is like ***global*** variable, so you can reach/update his value inside `foo()`, when you create an anonymous method like

```
   `D foo = () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine(x);
        x = 2;
    };`
```

The method isn't run yet , it will run just after you called `foo()` therefore the output is 3,2.